# Is this a bug in Berkley Snap! or am I just missing something?

Tags: mit-scratch

I've created a "block" in Berkeley Snap! that implements Heron's Formula (calculating the area of a triangle given the length of the three sides).  It works but it reports an error.  I've included a screen shot below that sums it all up.  (FYI, there are three such blocks in the image below named HF2, HF and Herons Formula.  I created all three trying to fix the problem.)

The routine correctly calculates the value (~125.14), but it also reports an "inside error" that the "reporter didn't report."  But, as you can see in my block editor window, the block does report.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug?  (I don't want to report a bug on their [github](https://github.com/jmoenig/Snap--Build-Your-Own-Blocks) site, if I am missing something.)

BTW, I tagged this "mit-scratch" because there is no tag available for Berkeley Snap!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A discussion of this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/jmoenig/Snap--Build-Your-Own-Blocks/issues/1686).  Bottom line:  delete the last reporter block and then add a new one.  That should fix it.